# Customizing QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qcombobox, qstylesheet

I want to customize `QComboBox`. The behavior I'd like to see is a combo box where it's button (the down facing arrow), takes the whole area of the combo box when it's collapsed. I know that `QComboBox` is a `QPushButton` with a `QListWidget` (or some other widget). I'd like to change the `QPushButton` to take up the whole area. I'd like to also get rid of the area where the current selection is being displayed. Any tips will be appreciated!

Here's what I want :

[image]

I am able to control the width of the drop down list through `QComboBox::view()->setMinimumWidth()`. That way I can have a narrower combo box but a much wider drop down list. That part is done. Now I need to just have a button there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `QComboBox` button, actually *down arrow*, can be done by a style, using `down-arrow` style, however, since you require the selection to be not visible, you need to take care of other settings, the width of the combobox and the `drop-down` should probably to exactly match your image, example style to accomplish that:

```
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(arrow.png); /* Set combobox button */
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    width: 20px;  /* set the width of the drop down */
}

QComboBox {
    border: 0px;
    max-width: 20px; /* width of whole box */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just figured it out myself. I was having trouble to move the image, but I was able to accomplish that through "left" and "top" properties by giving them negative values.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it's very possible through style sheets. Here's what I did:

```
QComboBox::setStyleSheet(
QComboBox::down-arrow {
image: url(:/images/add_support_combo_box.png);
left: -50px;
top: -10px;
width: 500px;
height : 200px;}");
```

If you see "left" and "top" have negative values. This forces the image of the down arrow to move left and up.

Comment: Great, I am trying with `left` and `top` settings, it does not hide the selection for me, may be the whole thing depends on the image itself